# SQLAlchemy Filter based on a function of an a field of a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter a query based on a function of one of the properties of the table. For example assume, I have a table `Days` which has a property, `day` of the type `DateTime`. now I just want to select the rows that the day happens to be Monday, something like:

```
db.query(Days).filter(Days.days.strftime('%w')=='1')
```

but this does not work! SQLAlchemy somehow thinks the days is another table and strftime is not a property of that table. What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing queries, you have to realize that the columns you are accessing are SQLAlchemy columns, not Python values.  They will only be Python values once you are looking at an actual row from the result of the query.  When writing a query, you need to phrase it in terms of SQL expressions.

The date expressions differ between databases.  For PostgreSQL, use the `extract()` function, which returns a number 0 (Sunday) through 6 (Saturday).  For MySQL, use the `dayofweek` function, which returns a number 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday).

```
# PostgreSQL
from sqlalchemy.sql import extract
session.query(MyTable).filter(extract('dow', MyTable.my_date) == 1)

# MySQL
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(MyTable).filter(func.dayofweek(MyTable.my_date) == 2)
```